# Poetry where the end of the line fits with the next

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Not sure if I need a word or a phrase but I'm looking for something to describe a term for poetry/song lyrics where the end of each line fits with its own line and the following line

e.g. Alice Cooper's Hell Is Living Without You is sung as

> Hell is living without your love
>
> Ain't nothing without your
>
> Touch me
>
> Heaven would be like hell
>
> Is living without you

But the emphasis could be changed to

> Hell is living without
>
> your love ain't nothing without your touch
>
> me Heaven would be like
>
> hell is living without you

Okay so the 3rd line doesn't work so well, I'll try and find a better example

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the word 'enjambment'. It is a fancy way to say 'line-break' and is often used to discuss poetry. More specific terms are ' end stopped' and 'caesura.' The former refers to a line break that coincides with a period or other punctuation mark, and the latter refers to a line break that does not, causing a word to be stressed.

This website provides better detail: http://www.reed.edu/english/intra/4.4.html

Comment: Hmm I think emjambment is close as it describes the sentence continuing onto the next line. I suppose what I meant was more that the end of the line can fit with either line but doesn't make sense together. As in the above example "Hell is living without your love ain't nothing without your touch" doesn't make sense

Comment: I admit I didn't fully understand the question, but I can't think of any specific word for what you are describing. Sorry I can't be of more help.